# What is the role of "von" when specifying a person?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, meaning-in-context

I've asked a phrase translation:

**Original sentence:**

> Past friday the server at xxx stopped, disk failure, I have been dealing with this ever since!

**The suggested translation was:**

> Am letzten Freitag funktionierte der Server xxx, wegen eines Festplattenausfalls, nicht mehr. Seitdem beschäftige ich mich mit ihm.

But then, the problem arises, when the provider of said translation mentioned that *if xxx was a person, the translation would have to be adjusted*:

> ...funktionierte der Server von xxx, wegen...

So I am wondering, what's the role of "von" in this scenario?

Comment: Side note: you don't need the commas in *"...  der Server xxx, wegen eines Festplattenausfalls, nicht mehr. "* (*wegen* is a preposition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the original translation, it is assumed that *xxx* is the **name** of the server (as in the fully-qualified domain name, for example).

Incidentally, that translation is incorrect, as the English original says "the server **at** *xxx*", meaning *xxx* is a **place** (and not a name).

So, the correct German translation would be:

> Am letzten Freitag funktionierte der Server **in** xxx wegen eines Festplattenausfalls nicht mehr. Seitdem beschäftige ich mich mit ihm.

So, *in* (in German) declares a place or position. *von*, defines ownership (in this case).

Comment: Simple enough! Thanks for the extra clarification regarding the "in" *(German)* and the "at" *(English)* :)

Comment: I disagree. I would never use German "in" with a fully-qualified domain name such as german.stackexchange.com, but I'd say "the server at german.stackexchange.com", as a domain name is also an address. In Germna, I'd either use it as a name ("der Server german.stackexchange.com"), or I'd use "der Server unter der Adresse german.stackexchange.com".

Comment: @wolfgang: I'm pretty sure there is a misunderstanding, because I'm having a hard time relating your comment to my answer.

Comment: @oliver: Let me rephrase. You claim that the original translation is incorrect, and "at xxx" should be translated as "in xxx", as xxx refers to a place. However, "at xxx" in the context of a server usually refers to its address, also known as its fully qualified domain name, so the translation without preposition is correct. With a domain name, German "in" can't be used.

Comment: @wolfgang: Ah, got it. :)

Comment: NB that ownership could also be shown with the genitiv: "xxxs Server"; no need for a preposition here.

Answer (score 15):

english "to stop" is in german "anhalten" (The server stopped - Der Server hielt an), but in context of a server I would prefere "ausfallen" (Der Server fiel aus).

---

Identify the server by its name:

> english: The server mail.example.org stopped.
>   german: Der Server mail.example.org fiel aus.

No prepositions needed.

---

Identify the server by its place:

> english: The server **at** Vienna stopped.
>   german: Der Server **in** Wien fiel aus.

Use preposition of place.

---

Identify the server by its owner:

> english: The server **of** Thomas stopped.
>   german: Der Server **von** Thomas fiel aus.

Use preposition of ownership.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the extensive base of comparison.

Comment: A server's name is also it's address. Therefore, you can say "The server *at* mail.example.org stopped" in English. (german: "Der Server unter der Adresse mail.example.org fiel aus")